# How to prevent partial query match with searchkick and word_start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I must be missing something. Here is my basic setup:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
     searchkick word_start: [:name]
end
```

When I search like so:

```
Tag.search('advertising', fields:[{name: :word_start}])
```

All is fine. However when the query includes multiple words as:

```
Tag.search('click to talk', fields:[{name: :word_start}])
```

I end up with a whole bunch of undesirable results i.e. *'Toys', 'Tools', 'Touch'*. Presumably because the token *'to'* matches the start of those words. I can't use `text_start` because I want *'advertising'* to match *'mobile advertising'*. Ideally, I would just like to prevent the partial match of the query, but allow partial matches on the index.

I've tried quotes:

```
Tag.search('"click to talk"', fields:[{name: :word_start}])
```

It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: What's the reason for using `:word_start` over `fields: [:name]`?

Comment: well I want to partial  match "word start" on the whole query.  If I remove that I get no partial match at all. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Try it without word start and let me know which cases don't work as expected (trying to better understand the problem a bit better).

Comment: Without `:word_start`, 'advertising' does not match 'mobile advertising'. With `:word_start`, 'click to talk' matches 'toys'

Answer (score 2):

With the default `:word`, 'advertising' should match 'mobile advertising'. The undesired results for 'click to talk' might be getting returned because of `misspellings`, try setting that to `false` and see if it cuts out the noise.

```
Tag.search("click to talk", fields: [:name], misspellings: false)
```

Comment: this is a reasonable idea. misspellings default to true has caused some weird results in the past